# Sinon-chai expect String to contain substrings in specified order

Tags: sinon-chai

Is there a way in sinon-chai to test whether a string contains sub-strings in the specified order? Something like:

```
expect("Hello World, it's a lovely day!").to.contain.in.order("World", "day")
```

Similar to what the [sinon-chai-in-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-chai-in-order) does for spy calls.

I am currently using a regexp matching similar to this:

```
expect(vm.$el.querySelector('table').textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ''))
  .to.match(/.*A.*B.*D.*C.*/)
```

Originally, I was doing the following, but for I am not sure why it doesn't match across the newline:

```
expect(vm.$el.querySelector('table').textContent)
  .to.match(/.*A.*B.*D.*C.*/gm)
```

However these matches can be sometimes hard to read and readability is the reason I am using sinon-chai.

Comment: If you're using ES6, you could improve readability using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like this: `expect('Jonathan Conway').to.match(new RegExp(``${firstName}.*${lastName}``))`